# maven-assembly-plugin for certain files

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the multi module project this is the parent pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atoms</groupId>
    <artifactId>atoms-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <url/>
    <modules>
        <module>atoms-persistence</module>
        <module>atoms-reglas</module>
        <module>atoms-webservice</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assemble.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the project atoms-persitence I have the following files:

com.atoms.vo.*

com.atoms.service.*

com.atoms.dao.*

And in the atoms-reglas I have:

com.atoms.rules.*

how can I user the assembly plugin to make a jar that have only  the classes in:

com.atoms.vo.* and com.atoms.rules.*  ?

Comment: I've answered your comment. Please provide the updated pom.xml showing the version of the maven-assembly-plugin you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
<assembly>
    <id>atoms</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}/target/classes
            </directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>com/atoms/vo.**</include>
                <include>com/atoms/rules/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: where to add the <assembly>, inside the <configuration> tag ?

Comment: project -> build -> plugins -> plugin... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Answer (score 1):

First, explicitly specify that you want to use a version of the maven assembly plugin greater or equal to 2.2-beta-3 in your `pom.xml` (the `includes`/`excludes` of the `unpackOptions` element that you'll need later don't behave as expected in versions prior to 2.2-beta-3). I'm using version 2.2-beta-4 here:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>assemble.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, declare a `moduleSets` with the modules of your choice and specify that you want to unpack their binary content using `includes` in your `assembly.xml`:

```
<assembly>
  <id>my-assembly</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <includes>
        <include>com.atoms:atoms-persistence</include>
        <include>com.atoms:atoms-reglas</include>
      </includes>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
          <includes>
            <include>com/atoms/vo/**</include>
            <include>com/atoms/rules/**</include>
          </includes>
        </unpackOptions>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Finally, run the following command from the parent project:

```
mvn clean package assembly:assembly
```

This builds a `target/atoms-parent-1.0-my-assembly.jar` containing only the wanted classes.

Comment: Did you update your pom.xml to use version **2.2-beta-4** (or 2.2-beta-3) of the maven-assembly-plugin? I tested this before to post it. Please, provide the updated version of your pom.xml.

Comment: Yes I try with 2.2-beta-4 

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assemble.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

Comment: Please update your question and provide more information about your setup and the actual result. As I said, I tested this and it's working fine with maven 2.2.1 and the maven-assembly-plugin 2.2-beta-4.